# Entity Framework - Foreign Key not set (0 / null) but navigation property is not null

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I've been stuck on this problem for quite some time. I'm using Fluent API Code-First to design a Database (EF 6.1). The problem is that when I add a new object, I can access entities in that object by their navigation property but the FK is 0 or NULL (in case of required and optional respectively). They are one-to-one relationships and I have tried both bidirectional and unidirectional.

Below is part of the code (Simplified, but only by including less entities):

```
public class Template
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int XmlDocId{ get; set; }
    public virtual XmlDoc XmlDoc { get; set; }

    public int? OtherXmlDocId{ get; set; }
    public virtual OtherXmlDoc OtherXmlDoc { get; set; }
}

public class XmlDoc 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string RawXml { get; set; }
}

public class OtherXmlDoc 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string RawXml { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Template> Templates { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<XmlDoc> XmlDocs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<OtherXmlDoc> OtherXmlDocs { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        ConfigureTemplates(modelBuilder);
    }

    private void ConfigureTemplates(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Template>()
            .HasRequired<XmlDoc>(c => c.XmlDoc)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

        // XML SCHEMA, delete with TT (optional)
        modelBuilder.Entity<Template>()
            .HasOptional<OtherXmlDoc>(c => c.OtherXmlDoc)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}
```

Now when I seed the database in my configuration files all the entities are loaded correctly (FK's correspond etc.). However when I try to add an object as below, the `XmlDocId` is 0, while the navigation property object (`XmlDoc` is not null and it has `Id` 3. The same is true for `OtherXmlDocId` and `OtherXmlDoc` except that the Id is null. An example of the add method below:

```
public void Add(string xmlString1, string xmlString2)
{
    XmlDoc firstDoc = new XmlDoc { rawXml = xmlString1 };
    OtherXmlDoc secondDoc = new OtherXmlDoc { rawXml = xmlString2 };

    var entity = new Template
    {
        XmlDoc = firstDoc,
        OtherXmlDoc = secondDoc
    }

    context.Templates.Add(entity);

    context.SaveChanges();

}
```

I'm really stuck at this. I've tried changing many things, flattening the DB, using Data Annotations only and wasted many hours. Hopefully someone can help :). Many thanks in advance!

**EDIT I**: So during debugging, when the object is created the `XmlDocId` and `OtherXmlDocId` are 0/null which is logical since they aren't added to their respective tables yet and as such have no Id. However, to my understanding, when I call `SaveChanges()` EF automatically detects all changes and applies them, which should update the FK's ([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556205.aspx)).

**EDIT II**: What "solves" the problem is explicitly setting the FK's after `SaveChanges()` is called (`Template.XmlDocId = Template.XmlDoc.Id`) but ofcourse this is not the solution I'm after. I use EF to abstract these manual actions and handle it all for me.

Comment: Does the PK on the Templates table have auto increment enabled?

Comment: I have not explicitly set it but I assume it works since I can add Templates and their PK's are correct.

Comment: Have you looked at your tables? There are no foreign key constraints in `Templates` table and I guess both Ids are treated just like fields.

Comment: You are right. The table definition has no FK Constraint for those entities. However shouldn't EF automatically infer those fields to be the FK due to *Id variable names? ([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx)) Anyhow, how do I explicitly set the FK Constraint through Fluent API or data annotations so I can check if this solves it?

Comment: It normally would. But here you are getting this because of the way you have configured the relationship. In fact `Id` columns in the other tables (which are PK) are also FK to `Templates` table. The `Templates` table is the "owner" (principal) of the relation. I don't know if that was your intention. It's like "this doc is for this template only. deleting template deletes the doc. doc.Id is same as template.Id`.

Comment: Yes it was the intention that the Template is the owner of the docs, but if I interpret your answer correctly it means we can not set a FK if it's a 'principal relationship' (or whatever it's called). So I can fix it now. But that means I can't use RequiredPrincipal()? Should I make it a bidirectional relationship so EF knows it's a one-to-one relationship?

Comment: I think you don't understand the problem. It's not what you see in your object. After `SaveChanges`, you have `0` and `null` in your db table record. If you want these Id fields to be FK, it requires totally different configuration (and db table/column/key structure). Again, all that depends of what is your intention.

Comment: I think I do understand it now. Maybe you could repost your comments as an answer so I can accept and upvote it? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `one-to-one` relationships, `Template` is the **principal** while `XmlDoc` and `OtherXmlDoc` are the **dependents**. Which means that `Template` does not have foreign keys, but the opposite - the PK `Id` column in `XmlDoc` / `OtherXmlDoc` is also a FK to `Template`. Hence `XmlDocId` and `OtherXmlDocId` columns do not play any role in the relationships and EF treats them as regular data columns and does not synchronize them with the navigation properties.

Shortly, they are redundant and you should simply remove them and use the navigation properties (after `SaveChanges`, the `Id` of a non null navigation property will always be the same as the `entity.Id`). Also it's good to add the inverse navigation properties, so the final model/setup could be like this

```
public class Template
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual XmlDoc XmlDoc { get; set; }
    public virtual OtherXmlDoc OtherXmlDoc { get; set; }
}

public class XmlDoc
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string RawXml { get; set; }
    public virtual Template Template { get; set; }
}

public class OtherXmlDoc
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string RawXml { get; set; }
    public virtual Template Template { get; set; }
}

private void ConfigureTemplates(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Template>()
        .HasRequired<XmlDoc>(t => t.XmlDoc)
        .WithRequiredPrincipal(d => d.Template)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Template>()
        .HasOptional<OtherXmlDoc>(t => t.OtherXmlDoc)
        .WithOptionalPrincipal(d => d.Template)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if mentioning foreign key explicitly helps:

```
public class Template
{
public int Id { get; set; }

public int XmlDocId{ get; set; }

[ForeignKey("XmlDocId")]
public virtual XmlDoc XmlDoc { get; set; }

public int? OtherXmlDocId{ get; set; }

[ForeignKey("OtherXmlDocId")]
public virtual OtherXmlDoc OtherXmlDoc { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I already tried that but it's not working and doesn't work that way: _'The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'XmlDoc' on type 'Template' is not valid. The foreign key name 'XmlDocId' was not found on the dependent 'XmlDoc' The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names._ I changed it to `[ForeignKey("Id")]'`which lets me seed the DB but when adding new data their FK's still are 0/NULL.